# How can I express two types are consistent?

Tags: python, python-typing

Say I'm using libraries that handle Json and they both define their own types that I know are consistent in the sense of [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#summary-of-gradual-typing).

How can I express that?

```py
from A import create_some_json
from B import consume_some_json

# and the types are 
create_some_json: Callable[[...], A.JsonValue]
consume_some_json: Callable[[B.JsonValue], ...]
```

I know I can use `typing.cast` when I write a function that uses the return value of one and passes it to the other. And that's okay-ish, I guess. But this becomes cumbersome with api's that use combinators, like e.g. `hypothesis.SearchStrategy`. Do I really have to pollute the call-stack with a decorator that does the cast, just for the type checker? And with this example, given the nested nature of Json; what happens with the types of the contents of a Json container when I cast it to the type of the other library? Or in other words: what does a cast called on a generic do to its covariance?

Comment: Do the `create_some_json` and `consume_some_json` functions come from an external library, or are they a part of your own code?

Comment: @Pierrecouy, external. If they were part of my own code, I'd make them use common types.

Comment: That why I asked ;) what library is this? Does it include its own type annotations?

Comment: the cast is just telling the type checker "I am telling you to trust me and consider that this variable is of this type". The variance is now of the type you are casting to, because you just told the type checker "this is now of this type". It's a stop gap. I guess that is what you are asking for here, otherwise, the principled way to do this is to write a function that takes one type and does the conversion to another.

Comment: Yeah, there is no way to properly answer this without concrete types. Just because `A.JsonValue` and `B.JsonValue` come from different libraries does not mean they will be incompatible. And if they _are_ consistent, then you don't need to do anything additional. If they aren't you need to make sure that is just an oversight on behalf of the library/stubs maintainers and not an _actual_ inconsistency that can bite you at runtime. If it just a too narrow/broad type alias by a library, you can use a `# type: ignore` directive as alternative to `cast`.